# Chromium and Firefox not working after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, snap, chromium

Unable to open with icon. When run from command line it says

```
$firefox

/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope is not cgroup
```

Other snap applications like android studio, pycharm, gnome calculator working fine

Edit:I removed firefox from snap and installed as regular app. But I can't do that with Chromium, cause I have lots of data. can't risk :). Also, I use Chromium for remote desktop to connect office PC. I need it.

Comment: Why can we not know what command you use to run it on the command line?

Comment: Simply typing $firefox

Answer (score 1):

The [solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1951491) for this is:

```
sudo apt install dbus-user-session 
systemctl --user start dbus.service
```

If that is not enough you also need to do this:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus"
```

(and start firefox or chromium) If that works you can add these 2 commands at the end of ONE of these files:

```
~/.profile
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/20dbus_xdg-runtime
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/75dbus_dbus-launch
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/95dbus_update-activation-env
```

Comment: It says

```

$ systemctl --user start dbus.service
Failed to start dbus.service: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
See user logs and 'systemctl --user status dbus.service' for details.

```

Comment: After adding these two

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus"

It says 

```
$ systemctl --user start dbus.service
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

``

Comment: I have added export line to . profile file... I NO LONGER HAVE ACCESS TO THE SYSTEM... IT SIMPLY REFUSING TO LOGIN... GOD HOW DO I FIX THIS.. HOW DO I EDIT . profile file with out loging in

Comment: I edited .profile file using tty at login...THANK GOD...Now I can login

Comment: @LinuxisLove cool :) do upvote and accept the answer if you like OR if you made other changes make you own answer and accept that and I'll remove mine ;)

Comment: That didn't solve the problem...Chromium is not opening...Im trying to find answer...thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own solution

I removed firefox from snap and installed as a regular application

For Chromium, I'm running it from command line. Created an alias like this

```
alias chrm='/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome'
```

For a specific profile:

```
alias work='/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --user-data-dir="/home/ubuntu18/ChromiumProfiles/Work"'
```

Not a neat solution, but it works. I appreciate if someone answers the proper solution